# Disabling and enabling css transition to initialize position

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

In javascript I want to position divs with rotations without transitions to reach a starting position for an animation (made with css transition).
So after this initial position, I want to enable the transition.

I did a codepen there:  http://codepen.io/3MO/pen/ZLoKbv
It seems the codepen does not work will it works on my local, the window.onload is not taken into account.

Anyway :
- the divs don't have any transition attribues set.
- I transform the divs, according to the digit clicked.
- After that, I want to start transitions, so I add a class to the divs which defines the transition properties.

```
function onThumbnailClick(event) {
   var index = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);

   //initialize the div position without transition :
   initPortraitPanel(index); 
   //then I "activate" the transition :
   $('.portraitDiv').addClass('active-transition'); 
   //After that I want to launch transitions...
}      

.active-transition {
      transition: 0.5s;
}
```

The problem is, the initial positioning of the divs takes the transition properties even if they are set after.

anybody can tell me a proper way to disable transition for an initial positioning, then activate the transition so this initial positioning doesn't use transition?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include jQuery to get the codepen example to work.  In future if something isn't working look at the browser console before you do anything else ;)

Comment: Thanks, I added it, so now it works.

Comment: Having a really difficult time understanding your question. Can you explain clearer what the problem is?

Comment: Have you checked my code?  My divs don't have any transitions defined in their css classes. I want to 1) position them, using transform, so they have an initial position without transition. 2) activate transition by adding a class. The problem is, even without transition defined, a transition of 0.5s is second:  in my code, I do the transformation in initPortraitPanel, and I add the class 'active-transition" AFTER, and it is still taken into account in the transformations applied BEFORE.

Comment: To be even more precise and direct:  on my codepen, when clicking on 1, 2, 3 or 4, the divs should position themselves without transitions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a timeout to the addClass :

```
function onThumbnailClick(event) {
    var index = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);

    initPortraitPanel(index);
    $('.portraitDiv').setTimeout(addClass('active-transition'), 50);
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgjRzZ)

Seems that this was already answered , downvoted, and deleted  ... I don't know why

Comment: @Kevin Jimenez  Seems that you already knew the answer. Am I missing something ?

Comment: adding a timeout seems a dirty solution, doesn't it? I mean, how do you set the duration? Empirical experience? But so it will depend on the browsers... It would be my last ditch hope solution.  I was trying to find an event triggered when a position is reached, without transition, but it seems it does not exist

Comment: No, it isn't a dirty solution. It's the cleaner one. The amount of the timeout doesn't matter, and in most browsers can be 0. The key issue here is to allow a browser render between the 2 functions. (initPortraitPanel and adding the class)

Comment: Ok thanks. Isn't it strange that the transition shows in the first place, while the initial positioning should be instantaneous? I don't understand the inner mechanism which explains the  behavior I am trying to solve.

Comment: Looking to this issue, I have found a better answer to this same question. Look also at transistor09 answer, it is the other approach that can be taken (the dirtier one)

Comment: Thanks a lot, so indeed it seems a normal behavior and timing is of the essence.